# Listar arquivos de uma pasta via ftp com jquery ajax

Tags: c#, html, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

Preciso listar arquivos de uma pasta que fica em um **servidor via ftp**, como faço para accessar essa pasta ?

O usuário deve selecionar um **item de uma lista** `(<select><option></option></select>)` chamado **listarDiretorios** e no evento change faz a chamada via ajax para servidor **via FTP** para listar o **nome** dos Arquivos, seria algo assim: 
Desse jeito funciona ?

```
$('#**listarDiretorios**').on('change', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ftp://urldoservidor.meusite.com.br/DiretorioDeArquivos',
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {

            $("#listaDeArquios").empty();
            $("#listaDeArquios").append('<option value>Selecione...</option>');
            $.each(data, function (index, element) {
                $("#listaDeArquios").append('<option value="' + element.NomeArquivo + '">' + element.NomeArquivo + '</option>');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Obs.: tenho o Usuário e Senha de acesso para essa pasta.